# Crontab with Pytest having issue

Tags: python-3.x, cron, pytest

I am trying to automate my pytest script using crontab -e, but not working. I am using the following command:

```
12 19 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /data/smc/test_file.py  pytest -s test_file.py | tee -a myoutput.log
```

In other case (without using "pytest"), when I am using python script using crontab -e, that works like:

```
23 18 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /data/smc/test_file.py
```

Or, even when I use it manually from the python console, works just fine:

```
pytest -s test_file.py | tee -a myoutput.log
```

Can anyone help, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your cron expression be `12 19 * * *  pytest -s /data/smc/test_file.py | tee -a myoutput.log`?

Comment: tried, but din't work..

Comment: Can you check the logs in `myoutput.log` and `/var/log/messages` (given you're using CentOS)?

Comment: the logs in myoutput.log are only created when I run it manually, but not from cron..I'm using Debian..

Comment: Is this duplicated?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291608/can-pytest-run-at-a-pre-scheduled-time/53411883#53411883