# Can Pytest run at a pre-scheduled time?

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, pytest, scheduler

I am using pytest to run my tests using python3 script like below:

```
pytest -s test_file.py | tee -a myoutput.log
```

It works. Now I would like to run this at a specific time everyday, I tried "crontab -e" from linux console but failed. I mean there is no log added to "myoutput.log" file. Can anyone please help? thanks!

```
42 00 * * * /usr/bin/pytest pytest -s /data/smc/test_file.py | tee -a myoutput.log
```

Comment: If you could perhaps add a little more detail to the "but failed" bit, that would go a long way toward helping us help you :-)

Comment: What's with the `/usr/bin/pytest pytest` part? I'm almost sure this is the error source.

Comment: Also, if the stdout of a command is empty, the common idiom in bash is to redirect the stderr output to stdout (`command 2>&1`), so if a command fails for some reasons, you are able to see the error in log. Try that if you still get an error after fixing the issue with two executables.

Comment: /usr/bin/pytest this is the environment and "pytest -s" is the command to run the file..when I am running the command from python console instead of crontab it works fine though..

Comment: `/usr/bin/pytest` looks like a path to the `pytest` executable. `/usr/bin/pytest pytest` is wrong, omit one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done by using cron output. eg:

`42 00 * * * /usr/bin/pytest pytest -s /data/smc/test_file.py >> /Your-log-path.log 2>&1`

Comment: 42 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/pytest  /data/smc/test_file.py >> /Your-log-path.log 2>&1 This works now. I mean I am getting the pytest output as passed/failed results but I am loosing the outputs with print command which I was able to get with "pytest -s". Any clue, please?

Comment: finally got it working!      42 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/pytest /data/smc/test_file.py -s >> /Your-log-path.log 2>&1